# how to make an oval side box in css?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

It has such a design. The result I want to output is the blue box. but when I give border-radius: 32px etc.. it looks like red on the right. I want the edges to be slightly oval.

Note the black lines. The blue one has a little overflow. exactly what i want but how do i do it.

```
.box {
    border-radius: 32px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Reduce the border-radius values to some 20-25. It will work I guess

Comment: @AbinThaha didn't work. the edges are still very sharp

Comment: Also, it is important to consider the width and height of the box inorder to give a proper border-radius. Check that. Because, if the height and width of the box are 20px and if you give 10px as border-radius to it, the box will be a round. So

Comment: I thin this may be achieved via [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in this snippet, the right side of the box, I made the border-radius more and hence it will be more curved than that of the left side.

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 45px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 45px;
}
```

```html
<span></span>
```

Comment: But can you recreate the effect that he presented in question? I think this won't do.

Comment: Yeah, she wanted a round edges, as in oval shape, otherwise she can use the clip also if she wants a more accurate one. But still the clip also works the same way, otherwise, she can use an svg.